# Submatrices and indices using Eigen

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen, submatrix

I'm currently working on a MATLAB project and I'd like to re-implement the most computational-heavy parts using C++ and Eigen.
I'd like to know if there's a way to perform the following operation (MATLAB syntax):

```
B = A(A < 3);
```

For those who are not familiar with MATLAB, the above-mentioned command initializes a matrix B made of the cells in A whose values are less than 3.

I've seen from a post on the [Eigen forum](http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=74&t=47094) that it's possible to obtain the indices of interest by using:

```
MatrixXi indices = (A.array() < 3).cast<int>();
```

What I'd like to have is something like:

```
MatrixXd B = A(A.array() < 3);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is this question still valid? Or some methods for submatrix indexing have been developed meanwhile in Eigen?

Comment: AFAIK, there has been no improvement in this regard. Of course, I'll be glad of being proven wrong

Comment: Something stirs deep within the Eigen bitbucket repo, so we might be coming close to a nicer solution to this one. http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329#c27

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There currently is a [feature request](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/bz/show_bug.cgi?id=329) for selecting sub-matrices by indexing filed at the Eigen BugTracker system. Therefore, I doubt it will be possible that way.

The only workaround I could think of is to copy the data manually. Not very nice though.

Answer (score 10):

[libigl](http://igl.ethz.ch/projects/libigl/) has many wrappers for Eigen to make it feel more like MATLAB. In particular, there is a `slice` function so that you can call:

```
igl::slice(A,indices,B);
```

which is equivalent to MATLAB's

```
B = A(indices)
```

Comment: Is this a feature of libigl or libigl calls some Eigen method to do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can perform operations on selected elements only with `select()`, which is the equivalent for the ternary ?: operator. This is not exactly what you wanted, but should work in many cases.

```
MatrixXd B = (A.array() < 3).select(operation_on(A), MatrixXd::Zero(A.rows(), A.cols()));
```

This will fill B with zeros if A<3 and the result of any required operation on A otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The latest development available on master branch of Eigen allows to work with numerical indices.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52289332/eigen-array-indexing/52342718#52342718) is a similar request, that shows an example of numerical indexing