# Eigen boolean array slicing

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, slice, eigen

In MATLAB it is common to slice out values that satisfy some condition from a matrix/array (called [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)).

```
vec = [1 2 3 4 5];
condition = vec > 3;
vec(condition) = 3;
```

How do I do this in Eigen? So far I have:

```
Eigen::Matrix<bool, 1, 5> condition = vec.array() > 3;
```

Comment: dont have much experience with Eigen, but looks like you're looking for the `select` feature

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submatrices and indices using Eigen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540147/submatrices-and-indices-using-eigen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the answer to an similar question here: [Submatrices and indices using Eigen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540147/submatrices-and-indices-using-eigen), libigl adds this functionality to Eigen.

```
igl::slice(A,indices,B);
```

Is equivalent to

```
B = A(indices)
```

Comment: while it may be useful, it doesn't answer the question here. OP asked for the equivalent of MATLAB's `A(A>3)=3`, not how to extract a submatrix... The solution I showed is basically an element-wise ternary operator equivalent to: `m(i) = (m(i) > 3) ? 3 : m(i)`.

Comment: Browsing the docs, [`igl::slice_into`](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/master/include/igl/slice_into.cpp), is a closer match, but as far as I can tell, it only works for a list of indices, not a vector of logicals... Even their MATLAB-to-eigen/igl conversion table suggests using [`Eigen::select`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Select.html): http://libigl.github.io/libigl/matlab-to-eigen.html (see the `A(B == 0) = C(B==0)` statement).

Comment: `igl::slice_mask(vec,condition,output)`

Answer (score 16):

Try [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaec49d21e1bf32797180e5d21a489f98):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXi m(1, 5);
    m << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;
    m = (m.array() > 3).select(3, m);
    std::cout << m << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @srsci: what do you mean? The example above is working fine, it's practically straight out of the documentation..

Comment: Actually, for the given problem (i.e., capping of the values) just `m.cwiseMin(3)` should work (and is usually faster).