# Eigen: select function on complex matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I have this matlab code that I want to write in `Eigen`:

```
[V_K,D_K] = eig(K);
d_k = diag(D_K);
ind_k = find(d_k > 1e-8);
d_k(ind_k) = d_k(ind_k).^(-1/2);
K_half = V_K*diag(d_k)*V_K';
```

So far the code that I've written is (the last part is based following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16253415/eigen-boolean-array-slicing) example):

```
Eigen::EigenSolver<Eigen::MatrixXf> es (K,true);
Eigen::MatrixXcf v = es.eigenvalues();
v = (v.array()).select(1/std::sqrt(v),v);
```

This is obviously wrong (first of all, you cannot apply `std::sqrt(v)` on `Eigen::MatrixXcf`), but I didn't figure out how to write it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the example you linked to, you need to compare the `.array()` (`.real()`?) to `> 1e-8` and use Eigens functions (or [`unaryExpr`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a23fc4bf97168dee2516f85edcfd4cfe7)) to manipulate the values of the matrix:

```
v = (v.array().real() 
//            ^^^
//        can't compare complex numbers

    > 1e-8)
//   ^^^
//  Actually compare the number 
    .select(v.cwiseSqrt().cwiseInverse(), v);
//            ^^^
//         Use Eigens functions or alternatively unaryExpr

// In one line:
v = (v.array().real() > 1e-8).select(v.cwiseSqrt().cwiseInverse(), v);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you please tell me the difference with `unaryExpr`?

Comment: You could write your own function that would be applied to each value. Usually, it's better to use Eigens functions when available, as this allows vectorization and expression templates.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327550/different-eigenvector-and-eigenvalues-in-eigen-and-matlab-could-generate-errors) question?